# When trying to encrypt my Access Database it freezes, and after 10 mins says "System Resource Exceeded"

Tags: database, ms-access

I am trying to encrypt my MS Access Database with a password (annoying GDPR reasons), but when I try to do it (after opening Exclusively) I can choose my password, click OK, but then it just freezes for about 10 minutes, and then comes up with error message "System Resource Exceeded".

My Database is quite big at 1.8GB (near to 2GB limit), but unsure why I need so much system resource just to put a password on it.

Does anyone know for sure what this is about? I am guessing it's cos my database is too big, but that is not going to give an ideal solution as will have to remove data.

Thanks,

Benji

Comment: Encrpytion isn't as simple as "put a password on it". You've got the right idea, the database is too large to encrypt in its current state. This is not AES encryption, for instance (which does not increase size). Access 2007 (+ to the best of my knowledge) uses Microsoft CryptoAPI, which is marginally inefficient for compacting, and it likely the cause of your problem. If you haven't already, you could try creating a copy of the database and compacting it, in case its not the data, but errors in Access causing the database to be so large.

Answer (score 2):

Encrypting isn't *just adding a password*... It's changing all stored data into an encrypted form of the same data.

Access requires some space to encrypt the data. In fact, Access often requires space for many operations, and having a database very near that limit is not a good idea.

Of course, a compact & repair might size it down enough to make it possible to encrypt it, depending on your database.

Answer (score 0):

[Probably not what you want to hear(and I'm not a GDPR expert)]

It's very **hard** to be compliant with GDPR when having MS Access as your system. Unless you are using a proper backend server i.e. MySQL, MSSQL to enforce user privilege. GDPR explicitly says "you shouldn't process any data that you aren't authorised to"/ "Employees should not see/process a data that they are not entiteled/authorised to" (Sorry i don't have a link, i've read that in my new company GDPR policies).

Which I don't think you have a role-based/permission based system. Even if you encrypt your database file. Anyone can copy and take it home and try to decrypt it. You now have 72 hours time to report it to the authority but you wouldn't really know whether someone actually copied your file or not and how easy the file decryptable is i.e. potential loss of % of data. (you need to provide this information when you inform the authority)

Having said that, GDPR is mostly about identifying personal data. If your databse does not contain any personal data which can be identified to an individual, you can relax for a bit. If you or your company is not sharing your database via dropbox or any public place, you can relax too. However, if your organisation saving all the personal data in your access database and you don't have a role-based security, you will be requested to rewrite your system. If there is a way that anyone outside of your organisation has a way to access the file/data, you are in a serious trouble. This applies to your client's personal information as well as yours and your employee's personal data.

GDPR has around 99 articles and it would only grow more and much tigher. Which means, if you are taking initiatives towards "to be compliant with GDPR" why not do it in a proper way so you are covered for "most" possible scenarios?

For me that is,

1. Split your database. Keep your front-end for now and
2. Move your backend data to a proper Database server MS SQL, MySQL is free. They provide more security out of the box. At least split your db and manage linking tables via code.
3. Have role/permission based security. (I've done this in Ms Access. So yes possible)
4. Scroll through Stackoverflow and apply all possible security Access has :) disabling bypass key, compiling to accde, custom ribbon, etc.
5. If required, move slowly to a newer platform? ASP.NET is in wish list of many.

As i said, i'm not GDPR expert and it does not exist until 25th of may. If you encounter a problem to solve GDPR issue, then i'd suggest thinking a bit in advance will help.

Comment: Splitting and using a different front-end certainly is adviced, especially if you're nearing that 2GB limit. I highly recommend, however, to move any role-based security to the backend (yes, you can do something that looks like role-based security in Access, but since the tables are exposed through OLE automation, you can't really enforce it). If you handle Access like a client, and handle the security server side, you have a whole lot less to worry about.

Comment: sorry I never done access only as backend ;) yes access jet backend is not compatible for role-based security. I should have mentioned, I was refering to MySQL with stored procedures and views for role based security.

Comment: Hi all, thanks for all the good comments. Firstly, the database is held in a very secure environment and so we are confident we won't have the problem of copy and paste of the file, and generally are confident people will not be able to get to the database; basically you have to be connected to our network and our network only allows certain users to access this shared drive it's on.

Secondly, have tried compact and repair, do that regularly, and it's 1.8GB after that.

It seems best bet is to transfer to a different system, I will have to look into that.